Add-Migration does not see environment variables from launchSettings
I want to read environment variables from launchSettings.json file when I add
Add-Migration SomeMigrationName, but I get null.
My launchSettings file example below:
"MySomeProject.Local": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "dotnetRunMessages": true,
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "swagger",
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7799;http://localhost:7798",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Local",
    "REDIS_HOSTNAME": "10.10.10.10",
    "REDIS_PORT": "6379",
    "REDIS_PASSWORD": "12345",
  }
},

And I read environment variables as Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("REDIS_HOSTNAME")!
but I get these variables as null (when add migration).
Note that when I launch my project then I get full of environment (not null) variables from launchSettings.
